# How does a node.js application keep running when no new events are queued up?

Tags: node.js, libuv

My question is how does a node.js application, like a http server keep running even when no new events are present?

I thought the libuv event loop terminates when no new events are queued up.

Is it something like a while(true) {} loop with event listeners registered for events?

Here is a simple code example of my question:

```
var http = require("http");

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.write("Hello World!");
  response.end();
});

server.listen(8080);
```

Thanks

EDIT: We know from the [the libuv io loop doc](http://docs.libuv.org/en/stable/design.html#the-i-o-loop) that the loop has to be alive at the beginning of each loop iteration, meaning more events occurred thus more callbacks are registered to be executed.

In this example, an event listener is registered but the program exits after the single event is handled because no more events were fired before the next loop iteration.

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

eventEmitter.on('event1', function() {
  console.log('event1 has occured');
});

eventEmitter.emit('event1');
```

But in this example the program continues indefinitely because of the active timer.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('setTimeout callback occured');
}, 2000);
```

So what is keeping the loop alive (the active and ref’d handles) in the http server example?

Comment: I think the event loop terminates when there are no event _listeners_ (/callbacks) anymore.

Comment: Oh right, thanks! Reading [libuv docs](http://docs.libuv.org/en/stable/design.html#the-i-o-loop), namely _2. If the loop is alive an iteration is started, otherwise the loop will exit immediately. So, when is a loop considered to be alive? If a loop has active and ref’d handles, active requests or closing handles it’s considered to be alive._ does "active and referenced handles" mean event listeners (callbacks)?

Comment: From [the description of what a handle is](http://docs.libuv.org/en/stable/design.html#handles-and-requests), I would infer that (JS) event listeners and I/O callbacks (like the one you're passing to `http.createServer()` in your example) are "translated" to libuv handles.

Comment: Regular `EventEmitter` instances are implemented in pure JS and AFAIK don't require any underlying `libuv` support (the terminology is a bit confusing, there are libuv events and EventEmitter events, which aren't the same thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the HTTP server, a TCP socket will be created, which is backed by a uv_tcp_t handle. Since the socket is active (listening for incoming connections) the loop will keep running until you stop the HTTP server.

Timers are a bit tome complex because each Node Timer does not map to a uv_timer_t handle, but the principle is the same.